# Joining a column to itself

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was wondering if there is a way to do the following:
Say I have a column

```
time
10:35
12:40
12:55
```

Is there a way to create a table that joins to itself but effectively "drops" one cell down like that:

```
time ---------- time2
10:35 ---------- NULL            
12:40 ---------- 10:35
12:55 ---------- 12:40
```

Comment: Have a look at the LAG function: `select time, LAG(time) OVER (ORDER BY time)`

Answer (score 0):

Try: SELECT     table.time,  LAG(table.time) OVER (ORDER BY table.time)
FROM         dbo.table

Answer (score 0):

As @doneth suggests, what you're looking for is `LAG()` ([docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html)).

```
select time, lag(time) OVER (ORDER BY time) as time2 from time_table;
```

Working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6ab35/5)